# Why does the user not get a "transaction complete" or "success" confirmation message after submitting an online transaction?

Tags: civicontribute, iats

Just updated to CiviCRM 4.6.26 from 4.6.x. Using iATS 1.5.3. Using D7. The user does not experience a completed transaction even though the transaction is complete through iATS and shows complete on user record (and in iATS dashboard in civi). The submit or "make contribution" link appears to hang up. No confirmation is sent to user or administrator. This results in the user attempting to resubmit. Any solutions? Any troubleshooting tips?

BTW: we have changed no configurations on contribution/registration pages. Previously working. But now they all hang up, we get no confirmation or "success" notification on any of our pages.

This has been resolved here: [iATS Scheduled job for recurring payments does not "finish" in the logs. How can I fix this or troubleshoot further?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17343/iats-scheduled-job-for-recurring-payments-does-not-finish-in-the-logs-how-can/17387#17387)

Comment: Just to be clear: you suspect this is caused by the upgrade to 4.6.26? From what 4.6.x did you upgrade from?

Comment: This problem has been resolved here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17343/iats-scheduled-job-for-recurring-payments-does-not-finish-in-the-logs-how-can/17387#17387

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I'm not sure why this is no longer working for you.

- All our 4.6 sites have been upgraded to 4.6.26 and are using iATS
  1.5.3 and I've had no reports of anything breaking.
- I've just confirmed myself by making a donation to one of our projects that I
  get to the Thank you page.

There is a bit of Javascript on that Make Contribution button. Ask your developer/support to open up a Firebug/Console to start the hunt as to what may be going on with your Contribution page.

From your Comments I see DOMPDF is throwing an error -> it is known to blow up at times - best to disable PDF creation for your receipt. It's one of those obscure settings under Misc -> civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1 -> hit No on Attach PDF copy to receipts.

Comment: Thanks Karin. I believe we updated from 4.6.19? Not sure. I'll try to check that by looking at the archives. In any case, it appears to be a timeout issue: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 367001600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home/lifechallengesem/public_html/data/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Style.php on line 774

Comment: BTW: the recurring payments are not updating the next scheduled payment field in the tables either. So recurring payments are not completing in a way that prevents them from being triggered again. I have to go into the table to update the next scheduled.

Comment: Pretty sure it has nothing to do with the button. Memory allocation problem? Even so, don't know why a transaction would now exceed any memory limits, since nothing has changed regarding memory limits.

Comment: One more note: In troubleshooting, I did disable and then re-enable 1.5.3 just to be sure everything was re-engaged after update to 4.6.26. Still no luck. Transaction times out but shows up in iATS Payments Admin and User Record (and obviously, in the iATS server).

Comment: Hmmm...what could cause that last step in the process to time out like that?

Comment: Re: recurring: I just double checked and a recurring with 4.6.26 and 1.53 from early this AM -> had its next scheduled date properly advanced to March 14 - 2017, so not sure what's going on with that. Of course if you have set things up such that you're trying to send out receipts for every single recurring contribution and it was trying to attached DOMPDF receipts - then... perhaps it got stuck on that.

Comment: I've updated my answer -> see above;

Comment: Thanks. Made the change. Didn't work. I turned "Attach PDF" off and still timed out. I am going to contact the server administrator for any apache logs that might be relevant.

Comment: BTW: This is happening on ALL transactions, not just event registrations (The PDF creation configuration seems to only apply to event registrations).

Comment: Actually it does apply to online contributions as well - as the field/help explains: "Attach PDF copy to receipts Yes No - If enabled, CiviCRM sends PDF receipt as an attachment during event signup or online contribution."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53640/discussion-between-john-richardson-and-karing-semper-it).